# Ошибка 504 flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть скрипт вечного онлайна(ВК) написанный с помощью flask. При переходе на ссылку некоторое время, все работает, но затем выходит ошибка 504. Это ошибка - значит, что время, выделенное браузером на ответ серверу истекло. Но скрипт как раз и должен работать вечно (ну онлайн на то и вечный). Как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем я уже разобрался со всем, можно использовать мультпоточность (Thread), тогда можно вернуть сообщение об успехе, а вторым процессом выполнять сам скрипт и задержки не будте